# Force-unload or reset a crashed linux driver

Tags: drivers, video, modprobe

What options do I have to hard-reset a linux driver?

I have a problem with my USB-connected dvb tuners. They crash from time to time with a stack trace in the kernel log and disappear from the device manager. The application (tvheadend, which runs in a docker container) freezes and is not killable anymore, and the docker container can't shutdown, not even being killed.

As all this is connected to an unstable state of the driver, I wonder if it's possible to force-unload or reset it so that I can startup the whole dvb subsystem again without rebooting the machine?

The drivers in my case are `si2157` and `em28xx*`. Unloading using `modprobe -r` for all dvb-relevant modules fails because the devices are still in use by the frozen process.

Answer (score 0):

Unloading modules can be done with `rmmod -f`
Do note the part below where it says **DANGEROUS**

This might not work if it is completely blocked, The best approach might to try and get the drivers fixed, Maybe not to a "working" state, but at least to a "if it crashes make it possible to unload and retry" state

```
Usage:
        rmmod [options] modulename ...
Options:
        -f, --force       forces a module unload and may crash your
                          machine. This requires Forced Module Removal
                          option in your kernel. DANGEROUS
        -s, --syslog      print to syslog, not stderr
        -v, --verbose     enables more messages
        -V, --version     show version
        -h, --help        show this help
```

Comment: nope, `rmmod -f mc videodev tveeprom em28xx dvb_core em28xx_dvb` fails with errors like `could not remove module em28xx: Resource temporarily unavailable`, so far no solution found except rebooting the server